# PHP if/else statement radiobutton update rows

Tags: php

i got a if else statement that updates certain rows in my table by selecting a radiobutton. but if i submit i get Error, query failed.
so if radiobutton(studenten) is checked update all rows with the column (functie) "2".

PHP code:

```
$host="localhost"; // Host naam 
$gebruikersnaam="root"; // gebruikersnaam
$wachtwoord=""; // wachtwoord 
$db_naam="mailing"; // Db naam
$tbl_naam="users"; // Table na

$con= mysqli_connect("$host", "$gebruikersnaam", "$wachtwoord")or die("cannot connect"); 
 mysqli_select_db($con, "$db_naam")or die("cannot select DB");

// Get values van form 
 $onderwerp=$_POST['onderwerp'];
$bericht=$_POST['bericht'];
$datum = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$query1 ="SELECT * FROM users WHERE FUNCTIE = '1'";
$query2 ="SELECT * FROM users WHERE FUNCTIE = '2'";
$testResult = mysqli_query($con, $query1) or die('Err, query failed'); 
$testResult = mysqli_query($con, $query2) or die('Err, query failed'); 


if(isset($_POST['radio']) and ($_POST['radio'] == '1'))
{
$query1 ="INSERT into $tbl_naam(onderwerp, bericht, datum)VALUES('$onderwerp', '$bericht',' $datum ')";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query1) or die('Error, query1 failed');


die;
} elseif(isset($_POST['radio']) && $_POST['radio'] == '2') {
$query2 =" INSERT into $tbl_naam(onderwerp, bericht, datum)VALUES('$onderwerp', '$bericht',' $datum ')";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query2) or die('Error, query2 failed');
die;
}
```

and here is my HTML form:

```
<form action="sendmail.php" method="post">

        <div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-12">
<label  class="control-label">
        Aan *
        <input type="radio" name="radio" id="studenten" value="2">Studenten
        <input type="radio" name="radio" id="docenten" value="1">Docenten     

</label>
</div>
</div>


<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-md-12">
<label  class="control-label">
        Onderwerp *
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="onderwerp"      placeholder="Onderwerp" autocomplete="off" <?php  echo    isset($fields['email']) ? 'value ="' . e($fields['email']) .  '"' : '' ?>>

</label>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-md-12">
<label  class="control-label">
        Bericht *
        <textarea class="form-control" name="bericht" placeholder="plaats hier uw bericht" rows="6"></textarea>

</label>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <input class="btn btn-success"  type="submit" value="Versturen">
</div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Instead of doing `or die('Err, query failed')` why not use `or die(mysqli_error($con))` so that you get the real error?

Comment: Print `$query1` or `query2` before you execute them. Print mysqli_error. And let us know, what you've got.

Comment: @user4035 it shows me this: SELECT * FROM users WHERE functie = '1'Erreur de syntaxe près de 'WHERE functie ='1' à la ligne 1. i'm using wamp server and all the errors are in french, so i'm trying to change it now

Comment: @jessey.l Wait a second. It should print an INSERT statement, not SELECT. Please, `print $query1` and `$query2` exactly after it is defined as INSERT. And try to run it in mysql directly.

Answer (score 0):

php $_POST get input filed value by its name and the name of both radio button is same, try this may be it works add this code to your html file

```
    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="studenten" value="2">Studenten
    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="docenten" value="1">Docenten
    <input type="hidden" name="valueToSubmit" id="radioValue" value="">

    <script>    

        var hidden = document.getElementById("radioValue");

        if (document.getElementById('studenten').checked) {
           hidden.value = document.getElementById('studenten').value;
        }

        if (document.getElementById('docenten').checked) {
           hidden.value = document.getElementById('docenten').value;
        }

   </script>
```

Change your php if conditions from this

```
if(isset($_POST['radio']) and ($_POST['radio'] == '1'))

elseif(isset($_POST['radio']) && $_POST['radio'] == '2')
```

to

```
if(isset($_POST['valueToSubmit']) && ($_POST['valueToSubmit'] == '1'))

else if(isset($_POST['valueToSubmit']) && ($_POST['valueToSubmit'] == '2'))
```

Comment: thanks for your help, the form runs without a problem but it only wont insert anything in my table